# [Weird problem]CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 4

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-alertdialog

I have this code to show an AlertDialog when taping on a marker in map:

```
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
            db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            String[] result_columns = new String[] {COL_DESCRI};

            Cursor cur = db.query(true, TABLE_COORD, result_columns,
             null, null, null, null, null, null);

            cur.moveToPosition(index-1);
                String description = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_DESCRI));

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Geo.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Infos.");
                dialog.setMessage(description);
                dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {    
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();



             cur.close();
             db.close();

            return true;
        }
```

The problem is that 3 markers of 4 are well working, by cons, there is one that is force closes the application. What could be he problem of that error? I maked `cur.moveToPosition(index-1);` and always the same problem.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `cur.moveToNext()`? It works for me

Comment: I have to make it in a loop, and if i do it i'll have all the alertdialogs shown when i tap on only one marker.